# How do you programmatically set MONGO_URL?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do I set MONGO_URL from within my Meteor app?

I tried

```
process.env.MONGO_URL = '...'
```

in my server-side code, outside Meteor.startup, but that isn't working.

I'm using demeteorizer to bundle it into a node.js app. I can't set MONGO_URL in Terminal directly (I'm running my app on a third-party provider).

Comment: Perhaps you could use [Meteor settings](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Meteorpedia: Environment Variables.](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables)

> #### Setting the value of an Environment Variable
>
> The safest time to do this with guaranteed behaviour for any variable
>   is BEFORE METEOR STARTS. **This is usually done either through your
>   PaaS provider's control panel for your app**, or in the shell script
>   that launches Meteor, e.g.
>
> **IMPORTANT**: You can also set/change an environment variable from inside Meteor, but you need to set it before it's used. e.g. **it's too late to
>   set MONGO_URL after Meteor has been loaded**, but MAIL_URL is ok since
>   you'll get it set before any mail is sent.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the default collection driver

```
MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver = _.once(function () {
  return new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(Meteor.settings.MONGO_URL, {
    oplogUrl: Meteor.settings.MONGO_OPLOG_URL
  });
});
```

or set it manually per collection

```
var database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(Meteor.settings.MONGO_URL, {
  oplogUrl: Meteor.settings.MONGO_OPLOG_URL
});

somecollection = new Mongo.Collection('somecollection', {_driver: database});
```

Comment: can you specify where exactly need to override default collection driver? inserting code to the main.js on the server side doesn't seem to work..

Comment: You need to make sure to do this before you create your collections. So ideally you have a package where you create all of your collections. And the first file you include is one that overrides the remote collection driver.

Comment: However I agree with the main answer -- using an environment variable is the best way to go.